# AS3 set cusor in textfield

Tags: actionscript-3, focus

I want that whenever the Fla is running, the focus will be on an input text called "inputField". Problem is, this doesn't work:

```
stage.focus = vcam.inputField;
```

This doesn't work, yes, you can type A - Z and 0 - 9, but for example Backspace doesn't work in the field, you have to click on it first.

Also, I have a seperate function that handles the arrow-keys and the ENTER key, so they may not be used by the inputField.

They only way I know around is for each key press making a function like this:

```
function inputHandle(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{

 if (event.keyCode == Keyboard./*keycode here*/)
  {
    vcam.inputField.text += "/*letter, number, or space*/";
  }

 if (event.keyCode == Keyboard./*another keycode here*/)
  {
    vcam.inputField.text += "/* anotherletter, number, or space*/";
  }

 /*And so on with every key*/
}
```

But that seems a little stupid to do, they're must be a faster way to do that!

Comment: More code is needed.  Complete textfield instantiation code, and the code that sets the focus on the textfield would be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more details on your case?

Because this works just fine for me:

```
package {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFieldType;

    public class asExample extends Sprite {

        public var inputTextField : TextField;

        public var focusButton : MovieClip;

        public function asExample() {
            inputTextField = new TextField();
            inputTextField.width = 300;
            inputTextField.height = 50;
            inputTextField.multiline = true;
            inputTextField.border = true;
            inputTextField.type = TextFieldType.INPUT;
            addChild(inputTextField);

            focusButton = new MovieClip();
            focusButton.x = inputTextField.x;
            focusButton.y = 60;
            focusButton.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
            focusButton.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
            focusButton.graphics.endFill();
            focusButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onFocusButtonClick);
            addChild(focusButton);
        }

        private function onFocusButtonClick(event : MouseEvent) : void {
            stage.focus = inputTextField;
            inputTextField.setSelection(0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Biggest problem, backspace doesn't work in the "inputField" if it is only selected by the "stage.focus". You have to click on it first in order go get backspace working. And because the focus is on that field, the handler for the Keyboard.ENTER doesn't work either.

Comment: Are you using the command `inputTextField.setSelection(0, 0)'?

Comment: Im usint a simular script to Skovalyov. And the same happens with his script, backspace doesn't work if you click on the field itself, so the cursor is in the field.